# How to make adb server not respond?

Tags: android, adb

We have test suite where adb clients connect to multiple android devices.
Our test suite raises these requests to connect, get device state and run applications in it.

I would like to simulate a scenario where adb server hangs. 
I tried issuing "adb kill-server" but any adb request from client starts the adb server.
Is there anyway we can stop the adb server from listening to adb client requests ?

Of course there is a long way of compiling adb service and changing the code our self.
But any easy way to get this done?

Comment: block the port used by the adb server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to still have a connection (that doesn't respond to commands), or is it fine to kill the connection altogether? Sounds to me like killing the connection would be fine since you say that you tried `adb kill-server`.

In that case, how about trying to connect to the device in TCP/IP mode without having set up the adb server to listen on a network port?  I.e. something like:

```
adb tcpip 12345
```

Comment: actually I was wondering we can reproduce the state where adb don't respond. As it might be useful in couple of scenario (say you are writing a tool on top of adb and you need to check adb state).

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion would be to actually disable adb interface totally in the device. While this may or may not stop the adb server, you would still get your desired result i.e no connection for adb clients.
The way this could be done is that on a ROOTED device, do

- `adb shell`
- `su`
- `echo 1 > /sys/class/android_usb/f_adb/on`

This one is what I could do on an HTC Vivid which I have on hand. For other devices, the paths might be different but they should all be similar. Once your reboot the phone, adb starts working again.